# How many local co-op players does Mario Kart 8 support?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I purchased Mario Kart 8 for my three children for Christmas. Before I wrap it I want to know if  they will all be able to race against each other at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they will.

Mario Kart 8 supports up to 4 players locally, so you (or your spouse) could play with (or against) your 3 children on the same Wii U.

Comment: Mario Kart 8 also supports up to 12 players online.

Comment: But only two local players when in online mode.